# ShoreTel P2V Audio Issue

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, voip, physical-to-virtual, shoretel

I recently P2V'd my ShoreTel server. After doing so everything seems fine. No errors anywhere, and everything looks good in Director except for a licensing issue since the mac address changed.

However, I have one other issue. When clicking voicemail, or calling the office, there is no audio playing. I can't hear any prompts whatsover anywhere. The windows audio service wasn't running initially, but I verified that was on and still had no success.

Has anyone experienced anything like this or have any input? Everything in the device manager looked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is too late to answer, but check did you install VMWare tools on the new virtualized server?  Also I checked my voicemail server and it looks like the window audio service is on "off" and our auto prompts/voicemail still works.  Thanks.